# Знаки препинания в СПП

Tags: спп, пунктуация

(1) Приятно слышать () и как стонет вьюга, и как злится за окном тайга. (2) Я не знал () ни где я нахожусь, ни как добраться до ближайшего жилья.
В приведенных примерах для связи однородных придаточных используются повторяющиеся союза И...И, НИ...НИ. Нужна ли в этом случае запятая, отделяющая главное предложение от придаточных?

Comment: Вот теперь автор вопроса "ищет подтверждения каким-то своим сомнениям")

Answer (score 3):

Если придаточные однородные, знаки препинания ставятся, как при однородных членах - между придаточными. Так что запятая, отделяющая главное от придаточного, не нужна.\

---

Добавляю в ответ на комментарий Софии по ответом Людмилы (в комментарий не вмещается).

Мне посчастливилось проходить специализацию у Аллы Федоровны Прияткиной. Она синтаксист, ею написаны некоторые главы Грамматики -80. Так вот она научила нас отличать правило и методический прием. (Я где-то в теме об Н и НН  об этом писала) Мы даже практические работы такие делали по школьным учебникам. Так вот то, что я написала в ответе - это правило, синтаксическая закономерность. Понимая ее, все остальное огромное правило можно не запоминать. А оглядка на союзы, одиночный он или повторяющийся - все это приемы, помогающие применить правило. Так как и про однородные члены: однородные члены разделяются запятой, кроме случаев, когда они соединены одиночным союзом И или союзом ИЛИ. Всё. Всё остальное - приемы. примеры и т.п. А в учебниках иногда по 5 страниц правил, которые некоторые учителя заставляют зазубривать. По молодости даже хотелось такой учебник написать, где бы все это было четко разделено: вот основное правило, а вот прием, которым можно пользоваться, чтобы правило применить. У нас же приемы выдаются за правила, поэтому несведущему человеку кажется, что они множатся и множатся, изменяются.

Comment: Ларf, спасибо за ваше мнение. Действительно, однородные придаточные ведут себя как однородные члены - поэтому и знаки препинания, и интонация предложения одинаковы. Но у меня есть еще похожее предложение с однородными придаточными: Я не знал () не то  я стою на опушке леса () не то за поляной начинается густая чаща. Как вы здесь поставите знаки и объясните их. Людмила, посмотрите, пожалуйста, тоже.

Comment: Я не знал: не то я стою на опушке леса, не то за поляной начинается густая чаща. Только я бы не называла это сложноподчиненным предложением. Быстрее было бы схемой показать, но здесь я не умею.  Это сложное предложение распадается на две части: до двоеточия и после. Между ними связь бессоюзная. Вторая часть представляет собой сложносочиненное предложение, между частями - запятая. Такие предложения еще называются многокомпонентными или сложным синтаксическим целым.

Comment: Но мне хотелось бы  это предложение оформить именно как СПП в таком виде: Я не знал, не то я стою на опушке леса, не то за поляной начинается густая чаща. Вот еще похожий вариант: Неясно было, то ли дым идёт от костра, то ли туман стелется над лугом.

Comment: И еще по поводу ПРАВИЛ. Ваш педагог излагал очень правильные мысли, но я пошла бы дальше: правило ЛЮБОГО УРОВНЯ должно объясняться и, в конечном счете,  сводиться к ИДЕЕ. Например, отсутствие запятой между однородными членами, соединенными одиночными союзами И/ИЛИ, объясняется их тесным грамматическим и интонационным единством – в этом случае мы как бы имеем одну синтаксическую единицу. А в наших учебниках правила всех уровней перемешаны и последовательно излагаются на пяти страницах безо всяких объяснений.

Comment: И поэтому так хотелось бы  увидеть такую идеальную школьную картинку. Учитель объясняет, что при наличии частицы НЕ или союза И запятая между главным и придаточным предложением не ставится. И слышит вопрос с последней парты: « Марья Ивановна, а почему?». И  Марья Ивановна не кричит раздраженно: «Петров  - дурак! Выйди в коридор!», а говорит: «А действительно, почему? Давайте, ребята, вместе подумаем.  К сожалению, в правилах об этом не написано».

Comment: София, современная школа живёт не только по тому учебнику, который зафиксирован в рабочем плане данного учителя.Мы учим искать ответ во многих источниках, благо, сейчас с источниками нет проблем.Такие Марьи Ивановны(первый вариант) давно ушли в прошлое, или их нужно гнать из школы.Мои дети учили правила(выполняли стандарт) и сами мыслили, искали ответ, целые научные дискуссии на уроках разгорались, а я им ещё противоречивых примерчиков подкидывала,потому многие и учатся в филологических вузах. От учителя многое зависит, а правила школьные - толчок мысли.

Answer (score 1):

1) Приятно слышать  и как стонет вьюга, и как злится за окном тайга. (2) Я не знал  ни где я нахожусь, ни как добраться до ближайшего жилья.

Запятая между главной частью и придаточной, присоединяемой простым союзом или союзным словом, не ставится:
а) если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит сочинительный союз и (или частица): Не вернул он мне книгу и когда прочитал ее; Скоро станет известно и кто приедет на праздник;

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134

Так что перед любым сочинительным союзом не ставится, в том числе и перед повторяющимся:Вспомните и что он сказал, и как он это сказал;
Студент не знал ни как называется произведение, ни кто его автор

Comment: Людмила, спасибо за информацию. Мне странно, что в правилах примеры с повторяющимися сочинительными союзами не приводятся, так что приходится домысливать расширение темы самим. Вот Ларf приводит четкое объяснение по поводу отсутствия запятых - Лопатин тоже мог бы нас порадовать.

Comment: В каких правилах и каких учебниках? Они все разные.

Comment: Я имела в виду Вашу ссылку, другой же Вы не привели. Вы говорите, что приветствуете научные дискуссии даже в школе. А можно мне задать несколько творческих вопросов по обсуждаемой теме (ваши ученики также могут их Вам задать):
А) Лосёнок теперь шёл не куда ему вздумается. – Почему при наличии частицы НЕ запятая не ставится?
Б) Я думал уж о форме плана и как героя назову. Какова структура предложения (соотношение сочинительной и подчинительной связи)?
В) Я не знал,  не то  я стою на опушке леса, не то за поляной начинается густая чаща. Нужна ли запятая после главной части перед НЕ ТО?

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно поставить знаки препинания и объяснить их выбор.

Пожалуйста, приступайте. Вам первое слово. Обсудим, поможем, объясним.

Comment: Инна, Вы на автора вопроса смотрите. Ясно же, София не школьница и не домашнее задание просит выполнить,  а ищет подтверждения каким-то своим сомнениям.

Comment: Инна, извините за неофициальный тон вопроса - он больше уместен в неформальной обстановке среди друзей. Думаю, все авторы тем должны  вести себя одинаково корректно.

Comment: И тем не менее, София, Вы-то свой категичный тон сменили (внесли коррективы в формулировку вопроса, который я процетировала)